# Why do I get the error "'0' was not found in the haystack"?

Tags: php, zend-framework, combobox, zend-form

I have two dependent comboboxes:

```
 $this->addElement('Select', 'Category',array(
         'label'      => 'Category:',
         'AutoComplete'=> true,              
         'multiOptions' => array('0' => '-Category-',$a->GetCategories(),'2' => '-Add             category-'),
         'required' => true ));

  $this->addElement('Select', 'SubCategory',array(
          'label'      => 'Sub Category:',
          'AutoComplete'=> true, 
          //'multiOptions' => array('0' => '-Select Category-'),
          'required' => true ));
```

I want to display the content of the second one so I do the following in the controller:

```
     if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {  //Le formulaire est-il posté ?
     $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost(); // récupère les infos des formulaires

     if ($form->isValid($formData)) { //Si le formulaire passe la validation
     $v = $form->getValues(); // On récupère les données du formulaire

     $Category= $v['Category'];
     $a=$form->getElement('Category')->getMultiOption('1');
     $cat=$a[$Category];

     $SubCategory =$v['SubCategory '];
     $b=$form->getElement('SubCategory')->getMultiOption($SubCategory);

     $this->view->test =  $b ;


     }

     else {$form->populate($formData);}

    /*Appel du web service d'authentification*/    
  }
```

When I click the submit button, the second combobox becomes empty and I get:

> '0' was not found in the haystack

Could someone please explain why this is?

Answer (score 10):

The error message is from the `inArray` validator. You can disable it by setting the proper key of your select element:

```
'registerInArrayValidator' => false
```

Comment: i try it doesn't work PS: the second combobox is filled using ajax

Comment: +1 - I know this is old, but I had the same issue with the second element being populated by AJAX and it *does* work correctly. `$form->getElement('xyz')->setRegisterInArrayValidator(false);`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're breaking MVC concept by calling `echo` from controller class.
Action controller doesn't have to produce any output. Only views must do that!

Comment: its just a test to see the content of the combobox

Comment: i'll change it to be conform with the MVC concept but the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable *inArray* validator totally or add options to select element before checking for the form validation. This way you are insured the select value is in range.